# How to use array of pointers in structure if i don't know array size

Tags: c

Suppose we have an array of pointers called `int *weights[]` in structure `Graph` and we initialize it

```
int CreateGraph(Graph *G, int vexs){
    G->n = vexs;
    for(int i = 0; i < G->n; i++){
        G->weights[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*G->n);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < G->n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<G->n; j++) {
            G->weights[i][j] = j;
        }
    }
    return 1;//just for test
}
```

also we have a function to show the graph

```
void show(Graph G){
    for(int i = 0; i<G.n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<G.n; j++) {
            printf("%d",G.weights[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

in main

```
Graph *g = (Graph *)malloc(sizeof(Graph));
CreateGraph(g, 3);
show(*g);
```

it crashed and xcode said EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0),but i have another worked version of function show

```
void success_show(Graph *G)
```

### Graph

```
typedef struct {
    int n;
    int *weights[];
}Graph;
```

### Question:

- What's the difference between using Graph *G and Graph G as function parameter here `show(Graph G) success_show(Graph *G)`.
- is it ok to initialize array of pointer using `G->weights[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*G->n);`

Comment: Please tell us where the crash happens, it's not clear in the question.

Comment: You need to read the chapters dealing with pointers. You obviously have no idea about the subject, therefore the questions is too broad.

Comment: You forgot restrict iterations in `for (int j = 0; G.n; j++)`. Should be like this: `for (int j = 0; j < G.n; j++)`

Comment: crashed at `printf("%d",G.weights[i][j])` in method `show`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to allocate memory for `G->weights`.

```
G->weights = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*)*G->n);
```

And then allocate memory for each individual pointer element.

```
for(i=0; i<G->n; i++)
{
    G->weights[i] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*<entersize>);
}
```

Comment: Please see [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)